# Is there a biological term for an activity period that is determined by temparature

Tags: zoology, ecology, ethology

In general we refer to the activity period of organisms in terms of the period of the day that they are active.  Diurnal, crepuscular, nocturnal, matutinal, and vespertine, for example.

There are certain desert animals whose activity patterns seem to match a temperature range more than they do the day/night pattern.  Is there a term for this type of activity pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt there is such term.

Note that diurnal and seasonal are likely pretty well correlated with the temperature cycle. The temperature cycle is, I would presume, mainly affected by the daily and seasonal cycle.

You can talk about a `behaviour that is dependent upon the temperature which fluctuates daily and seasonally`. Looking for specific keywords on Google Scholar, it appears that most authors go through short phrasing of the kind to express this concept.